# Session in owin katana OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin, katana

I am using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider for access token issuing. In the method GrantResourceOwnerCredentials I need available session to process some logic on my side. As it is not available  - it is REST web api, I have set as following in Global.asax :

```
    protected void Application_PostAuthorizeRequest()
    {
       HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.Required);         
    }
```

It is still null after this. What I have to do to enable the session here ?